# How to write your own custom GKMatchMakerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I'm having trouble starting to implement my own matchmaking UI (replacing GKMatchMakerViewController I think). The UI would be simple blank screen that would say "finding match".

My problem is, I'm not sure how to start. So I was wondering if anyone have any known tutorials that would cover the basics?

I did a google search and I just can't find any source code or documentation on how to do this, only the class reference :(

Thank you!

P.S also if you could point me in a direction into implementing a ranked match making system implementation that would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a match request with GKMatchMaker. Wait for the response.

In the meantime show a blank scene with a "finding match" label.

I believe there's no tutorial because it's that simple. :)

Comment: Do you have any more details than that? Or an example?